# Unity - In game TV set

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have some TV model, like
[image]

and C# code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ClicktoPlayWebMovieClass : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    
    }

    private Vector3 FindBoundCord (int i, GameObject _GameObject){
        /*This is basically where the code starts. It starts out by creating a 
           * bounding box around the target GameObject. 
          It calculates the 8 coordinates forming the bounding box, and 
          returns them all to the for loop.
          Because there are no real method which returns the coordinates 
          from the bounding box I had to create a switch/case which utillized 
          Bounds.center and Bounds.extents.*/
        
        Bounds _TargetBounds = _GameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds;
        Vector3 _TargetCenter = _TargetBounds.center;
        Vector3 _TargetExtents = _TargetBounds.extents;
        
        
        switch(i){
        case 0:
            return _TargetCenter + new Vector3(_TargetExtents.x, _TargetExtents.y, _TargetExtents.z); 
        case 1:
            return _TargetCenter + new Vector3(_TargetExtents.x, _TargetExtents.y, _TargetExtents.z*-1);
        case 2:
            return _TargetCenter + new Vector3(_TargetExtents.x, _TargetExtents.y*-1, _TargetExtents.z);
        case 3:
            return _TargetCenter + new Vector3(_TargetExtents.x, _TargetExtents.y*-1, _TargetExtents.z*-1);
        case 4:
            return _TargetCenter + new Vector3(_TargetExtents.x*-1, _TargetExtents.y, _TargetExtents.z);
        case 5:
            return _TargetCenter + new Vector3(_TargetExtents.x*-1, _TargetExtents.y, _TargetExtents.z*-1);
        case 6:
            return _TargetCenter + new Vector3(_TargetExtents.x*-1, _TargetExtents.y*-1, _TargetExtents.z);
        case 7:
            return _TargetCenter + new Vector3(_TargetExtents.x*-1, _TargetExtents.y*-1, _TargetExtents.z*-1);
        default:
            return Vector3.zero;
        }
        
    }

    IEnumerator MyMethod() {
        //Debug.Log("Before Waiting 2 seconds");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        //Debug.Log("After Waiting 2 Seconds");
    }

    public string url = "http://becunningandfulloftricks.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/hedgehog_in_the_fog.ogg";
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {


        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            Debug.Log("clicked");
            // Start download
            var www = new WWW(url);
            // Make sure the movie is ready to start before we start playing
            var movieTexture = www.movie;
            while (!movieTexture.isReadyToPlay) {
                StartCoroutine(MyMethod());
            }

            print("LOADED!!!");

            Vector2 _ObjectScreenCord, _Xmin = new Vector2(Screen.width,0), _Xmax = Vector2.zero, _Ymin = new Vector2(Screen.height,0), _Ymax = Vector2.zero;
            float _Height, _Width;    
            
            
            for(int i = 0; i != 8; i++){
                //FindBoundCord() locates the eight coordinates that forms the boundries, followed by converting the coordinates to screen space.
                // The entire script starts in FindBoundCord
                _ObjectScreenCord = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(FindBoundCord(i, transform.gameObject));
                
                /* After gathering the coordinates and converting them to screen space
              we try to locate which of these have the highest/minimum x and y values.
             The difference between highest/minimum x and y must correspond to
              width and height.*/
                
                if(_ObjectScreenCord.x > _Xmax.x){
                    _Xmax.x = _ObjectScreenCord.x;
                }
                else if(_ObjectScreenCord.x < _Xmin.x){
                    _Xmin.x = _ObjectScreenCord.x;
                }    
                if(_ObjectScreenCord.y > _Ymax.x){
                    _Ymax.x = _ObjectScreenCord.y;
                }
                else if(_ObjectScreenCord.y < _Ymin.x){
                    _Ymin.x = _ObjectScreenCord.y;
                }            
            }
            
            
            
            //Too measure the distance between them, I use the Vector2 method Distance.
            _Height = Vector2.Distance(_Ymax, _Ymin);
            if (_Height > Screen.height || _Height < 0){
                _Height = 0;
            }
            
            _Width = Vector2.Distance(_Xmax, _Xmin);
            if (_Width > Screen.width || _Width < 0){
                _Width = 0;
            }

            print(_Height+" - "+_Width);


            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = movieTexture;
            // Assign clip to audio source
            // Sync playback with audio
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = movieTexture.audioClip;
            // Play both movie & sound

            GUITexture gt = GetComponent<GUITexture>();
            gt.texture = movieTexture;


            transform.localScale = new Vector3 (0f,0f,0f);
            transform.position = new  Vector3 (0.5f,0.5f,0f);

            Rect r = gt.pixelInset;
            

            print(_Width);
            print(movieTexture.width / 2);

            r.xMin = -_Width / 2;
            r.xMax = _Width / 2;
            r.yMin = -_Height / 2;
            r.yMax = _Height / 2;

//          r.xMin = -movieTexture.width / 2;
//          r.xMax = movieTexture.width / 2;
//          r.yMin = -movieTexture.height / 2;
//          r.yMax = movieTexture.height / 2;

            gt.pixelInset=r;            
            movieTexture.Play();
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
        }
    }

}
```

When I'am clicking on my TV set, looks good:
[image]

It looks good until I am not rotate my camera. After camera rotation movieTexture has initial position on the screen:

[image]

and it makes my TV set broken...
How to specify movieTexture, that it must have position of the `GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture`? I need make to look something like this

[image]

But instead of screen of the TV must be video of the movieTexture at it must rotate, like screen of the TV set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at projectors? They do this pretty well and just changes the texture like you want. They are normally used for shadows but any texture can be projected on any model. 
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Projector.html

Comment: Hi. I can't understand, how to project movieTexture to the TV screen... Can you give me an example, ow to project movieTexture?